# Is there a maxium amount of "Draws" in PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

As the title says is there a max amount of objects you can draw using the GD library in PHP. Given the code below i can only get about 140 squares to appear. The line and square at the bottom only show if you don't max out the grid first. Anyone know of another way to get this done?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$png_image = imagecreate(3000, 3000);
imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);

$gridx = 100;
$gridy = 100;

$count = 0;
$currentx = 0;
$currenty = 0;

function makeRec($xpos, $ypos, $c1, $c2, $c3) {
    global $png_image, $currentx, $currenty;
    imagefilledrectangle($png_image, $xpos, $ypos, $xpos+10, $ypos+10, imagecolorallocate($png_image, $c1, $c2, $c3));
    $currentx = $xpos+11;
}
function makexLine($xpos, $ypos) {
    global $png_image, $currentx, $currenty;
    imageline($png_image, $xpos, $ypos, $xpos, $ypos+10, imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0));
    $currentx = $xpos+1;
}
function makeyLine($xpos, $ypos) {
    global $png_image, $currentx, $currenty;
    imageline($png_image, $xpos, $ypos, $xpos+100, $ypos, imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0));
    $currenty = $ypos+1;
}

for($y = 0; $y < $gridy; $y++) {
    makeyline($currentx, $currenty);
    for($x = 0; $x < $gridx; $x++) {
        makexLine($currentx, $currenty);
        if($count == 0) {
            makeRec($currentx, $currenty, 255, 1, 255);
            $count++;
        }
        else {
            makeRec($currentx, $currenty, 255, 255, 255);
            $count = 0;
        }
    }
    makexLine($currentx, $currenty);
    $currentx = 0;
    $currenty = $currenty + 11;
}
makeyline(0, 200);
makeRec(200, 200, 255, 1, 255);
imagepng($png_image);
imagedestroy($png_image);
```

?>

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe it's limited by maximum execution time and memory limit. What are your values? Try to raise them? What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a test script on my system that draws 1 million squares with `imagefilledrectangle()` in a chessboard pattern works fine (and surprisingly quickly).  If there is a draw limit it's at least that high.

Your problem seems to be too many calls to `imagecolorallocate()`.  Below I've modified your code to call `imagecolorallocate()` only once per colour:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
$png_image = imagecreate(3000, 3000);
imagecolorallocate($png_image, 15, 142, 210);

$magenta = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 255, 1, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 255, 255, 255);

$gridx = 100;
$gridy = 100;

$count = 0;
$currentx = 0;
$currenty = 0;

function makeRec($xpos, $ypos, $colour) {
    global $png_image, $currentx, $currenty;
    imagefilledrectangle($png_image, $xpos, $ypos, $xpos+10, $ypos+10, $colour);
    $currentx = $xpos+11;
}
function makexLine($xpos, $ypos, $colour) {
    global $png_image, $currentx, $currenty;
    imageline($png_image, $xpos, $ypos, $xpos, $ypos+10, $colour);
    $currentx = $xpos+1;
}
function makeyLine($xpos, $ypos, $colour) {
    global $png_image, $currentx, $currenty;
    imageline($png_image, $xpos, $ypos, $xpos+100, $ypos, $colour);
    $currenty = $ypos+1;
}

for($y = 0; $y < $gridy; $y++) {
    makeyline($currentx, $currenty, $black);
    for($x = 0; $x < $gridx; $x++) {
        makexLine($currentx, $currenty, $black);
        if($count == 0) {
            makeRec($currentx, $currenty, $magenta);
            $count++;
        }
        else {
            makeRec($currentx, $currenty, $white);
            $count = 0;
        }
    }
    makexLine($currentx, $currenty, $black);
    $currentx = 0;
    $currenty = $currenty + 11;
}
makeyline(0, 200, $black);
makeRec(200, 200, $magenta);
imagepng($png_image);
imagedestroy($png_image);
```

Comment: Thanks timclutton! That hit the nail on the head.